# What studies have been done in the areas of emotional hypersensitivity and over-offendedness?

Tags: emotion

It seems that emotional hypersensitivity and over-offendedness is on the rise. I've been trying to read up on it but it's hard to find scientifically backed material.

The website "Exploring your mind" has some interesting articles but I have no way of judging their accuracy. For example, [The Bad Habit of Being Offended by Everything](https://exploringyourmind.com/the-bad-habit-of-being-offended-by-everything/) which has a link to [Dealing With Hypersensitive People](https://exploringyourmind.com/dealing-hypersensitive-people/). While the information presented seems to make sense, it doesn't cite any authors, let alone peer reviewed papers.

What peer reviewed studies have been done in the areas of emotional hypersensitivity and over-offendedness?